# How can I get the floor of a large floating-point number at compile-time?

Tags: c++, floating-point, c++20, floor

I'm writing a compile-time math library using c++20, I already have floor/ceiling/abs/etc. but the method I am currently using to get the floor of a float is `n >= 0.0f ? (float)(long long)n : (float)(long long)n - 1.0f;` which is a pretty typical fast floor function. however for floats larger than long long max value this returns junk because I cast to a long long. I know using floorf works for large floats but it isn't constexpr (until c++23 which is still in preview). However I can't just copy what the stl is doing because it calls an intrinsic which itself isn't constexpr. Any information that could point me in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: Assuming you have IEEE754 float32, then if `abs(f)>(1<<23)`, `floor(f)==f`.

Comment: A 64-bit float larger than 64-bit `long long` cannot possibly have a fractional part anyway: there are not enough bits in the mantissa to represent it. Perhaps you can add a case whereby, if `n` is large enough, return it unchanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by @chtz and @IgorTandetnik floats large enough to be larger than long long max value can't store a fractional part so just return the input.

For floats:

```
if(abs(n) > (float)(1 << 23))
{
    return n;
}
else
{
    return n >= 0.0f ? (float)(long long)n : (float)(long long)n - 1.0f;
}
```

For doubles:

```
if(abs(n) > (double)(1i64 << 52))
{
    return n;
}
else
{
    return n >= 0.0 ? (double)(long long)n : (double)(long long)n - 1.0;
}
```

Edit: Here is a templated version with concepts:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <std::floating_point Type>
static constexpr Type FloorF(const Type& n) noexcept
{
    static constexpr Type MaxPrecision = 1i64 << (std::numeric_limits<Type>::digits - 1);

    return n > MaxPrecision ? n :
        n >= (Type)0 ? (Type)(long long)n : (Type)(long long)n - (Type)1;
}
```

Comment: Instead of magic numbers, please use `std::numeric_limits<float>` defined in `<limits>`. It is the portable way of dealing with arithmetic types.

Comment: I did end up creating a constant for that as to not use magic numbers, but where in numeric_limits has that constant? I assume you mean doing 1 << (std::numeric_limits<float>::digits - 1), but either way I'd define a separate constant.

Comment: You can make it a template to avoid duplication. And the portable way would be `std::scalebn(lim::radix, lim::digits -1)` rather than a simple shift(`using lim=std:: numeric_limits<float>;`). But `scalebn` is not `constexpr` prior to C++23.

Comment: I've already made a templated version, I've just updated the answer with my implementation.

Comment: fine consider `scalebn` and `radix` for future C++23 versions. That'd be more reliable.

Comment: The implied 1 bit in the mantissa of the IEEE format means it can hold one extra bit of precision beyond its physical size.  You may need to adjust your constants.